# Is 'godspeed' a religious term? (Can it be used without invoking religiosity nowadays?)

Tags: meaning, etymology

There is an [Urban Dictionary entry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=godspeed) saying

> Of Old English origin, shortening of "Good Speed," and contrary to
>   popular belief has nothing to do with God. People would say this to
>   others who were leaving on a long and perilous journey, wishing them
>   success, but more importantly wishing for their return.

Edited: Can it be used without invoking any nuance of religiosity ?

Well guys, I did check the references and did find the explanations which ended up becoming the answer for the question. What I meant was to get an educated opinion on the usage of the term in modern times.

How a question with so many votes gets put on hold is beyond me.

Comment: No it is not a religious term, but it carries  a religious connotation: ***Godspeed*** (interj.)
also God speed, by late 14c., ***"(I wish that) God (may) grant you success,"***  from God + speed (v.) in its old sense of "prosper, grow rich, succeed." ***Specifically as a salutation by mid-15c. Also in Middle English as an adverb, "quickly, speedily" (early 14c.);*** the then-identically spelled God and good seem to be mixed up in this word. From late 13c. as a surname. He may bidde god me spede is found in a text from c. 1300. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=godspeed

Comment: @josh61 I found that as well and I am trying to go a little deeper into the origins of the word.

Comment: you are actually citing the UD

Comment: @josh61 do you think one could fully veer from the religious meaning when using it?

Comment: FYI, the Urban Dictionary can be a useful way to look up informal meanings, particularly for novel or very new phrases/neologisms, but it's **not** a reliable reference for the English Language, in part because it's entirely crowd sourced, and is thus as reliable as, say, a YouTube comment thread.

Comment: @Max Williams hence my asking.

Comment: @SurvMach indeed.  There was an implied point (which I should have made more clear) that you could have looked it up in a more reliable reference source.

Comment: It is a set phrase which has lost its original religious origin and meaning. Just a way to wish success or a good fortune.

Comment: Hello, SurvMach. Please make sure you cite reference or dictionary definition when you ask a question. I edited your post. If you leave such a short post, it will be automatically flagged by the system.

Comment: In modern times we often lose track of the idea that God is a universal concept, not a specific religious deity.  It's the details and names that change, not the overall concept. So IMO the term "godspeed" is not religious per se, but indicates a speed of divine origin.

Comment: @Omegacron Note the phrasing: "religious term" rather than, say, "Christian term". The only question is whether or not the "god" half of the word is religious.

Comment: @Josh61 Your first comment could be an answer ;)

Comment: Posting: *How a question with so many votes gets put in hold is beyond me*. Is counterproductive. But it's great to hear that your research led you to the same conclusion, that the term God in "Godspeed" was originally religious. I'd venture to say that God still has strong religious connotations today, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @mari-lou a it is still in the title

Comment: The edited title (*Is 'godspeed' a religious term?* (*Can it be used without invoking religiosity nowadays?*)) is contradictory, if you concede that the expression might be evoked in a religious sense, then you admit that it is (or used to be) a religious term. You can't have it both ways. There is one vote cast to reopen, so you'll probably find supporters. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A please note I didn't ask 'Was godspeed a religious term?'

Comment: 'in hold' changed to 'on hold' (phone keyboard)

Comment: "educated opinion on the usage of the term in modern times?" - POB "Can it be used without invoking any nuance of religiosity?" - POB

Answer (score 48, accepted):

"God speed you" is an example of a term with religious **origins**.  Whether that makes it a "religious term" depends on what your definition of a "religious term" is.  It's pretty archaic now.

Perhaps surprisingly, it's not (originally) wishing "speed" to the person - it's from the old English word "spede" which means "success" (and from which "speed" is derived).  So it's saying "May god give success to you".

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Godspeed

There are several phrases in common usage which have religious origins - often they now exist in a contracted form which isn't obviously recognisable as religious.  For example, "goodbye", which is a contracted form of "God be with you".

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/goodbye#English

I think that most people wouldn't say that "goodbye" is a "religious term" (again, dependent on whatever that actually means), despite its religious origins.  Because "god speed you" clearly contains the word "god", it's  more *likely* to be described as religious, I would say.

Comment: I would say being archaic makes it mostly a "religious term". It's not regularly used in ordinary contemporary speech, so unless the speaker is just someone who always uses archaic speech as a hobby/quirk/whatever, you can assume there's a reason they chose to use it, and I suspect most people would assume that reason is related to the letters G-O-D.

Comment: @R.. Speaking as someone who uses archaic speech as a hobby, I don't think most people who do know and use this word would intend it as a religious sentiment.

Comment: @barbecue: I explicitly excluded speakers who use archaic speech as a hobby in my comment. For you, there are other most-plausible reasons. For someone who just says "godspeed" without otherwise using archaic language, not so much.

Comment: @R.. my attempt at humor may have disguised my true point. I do not believe that the majority of people who would use this word would intend it in a specifically religious manner. I doubt that the relevant Japanese documentary filmmaker and Canadian post-rock band had religion in mind.